# Funtions with two parameter not working in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, form-data, react-query, function-parameter

I have 2 files. One of them is "http" folder for requests, the other one is React Component. I have a problem when I want to change the form and upload a profile photo. Changing form is working (userDetails), but the photo object not working (UpdatedProfilePicture). The response comes back empty object.

I had an idea and tried. I changed the URL and deleted userDetails, and formData worked. But both of them not worked. Actually, the first parameter works, but the second parameter does not work. For request, I use React Query

**The Component**

```
  const { mutate } = useMutation(apiService.updateUserDetailsInfo);

  const onSubmit = () => {
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("photo", UpdatedProfilePicture);
    const urlUserDetails = new URLSearchParams(userDetails);

    mutate(urlUserDetails, formData);

  };
```

**The http folder**

```
     updateUserDetailsInfo: async (userDetails, formData) => {
      const response = await httpService.patch(`/user/detailsInfo?${userDetails}`, formData);
      return response?.data;
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`useMutation` doesn't support functions with multiple parameters, but you can put all the data into a single parameter instead:

```
updateUserDetailsInfo: async (variables) => {
  const { userDetails, formData } = variables;
  const response = await httpService.patch(`/user/detailsInfo?${userDetails}`, formData);
  return response?.data;
},

// used like:
const { mutate } = useMutation(apiService.updateUserDetailsInfo);

const onSubmit = () => {
  let formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("photo", UpdatedProfilePicture);
  const userDetails = new URLSearchParams(userDetails);

  mutate({ userDetails, formData });
};
```

Comment: it's worth noticing why that is, and the answer is that `.mutate` takes a second options argument, where you can pass additional callbacks for onSuccess, onError and onSettled. That wouldn't be easily possible with variadic arguments to the mutateFn.